# karate- Unable to perform certificate selection from version 0.7.0 onwards

Tags: karate

I am new to karate dsl and also new to coding.

I started an API project with karate version `0.6.0` and was able to connect to web service and also perform certificate selection with karate-jersey but when I updated to version `0.7.0` I started getting error as bad certificate. Can you help me on this?

I am using following line in my feature file:

```
configure ssl = { trustStore: 'classpath:truststore.jks', trustStorePassword: 'certpassword', trustStoreType: 'jks',keyStore: 'classpath:keyStore.p12', keyStorePassword: 'certpassword', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12',trustAll: 'true',algorithm: 'TLS' };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try upgrading to 0.8.0 please.

Also certificate handling was very difficult to implement and please read this ticket / thread to get a sense of anything we / you may have missed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/281

If you are still stuck, please follow the process here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

You can look at existing Karate integration tests to help you replicate your problem. This will be very much appreciated, as you can help fix Karate if applicable: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl

Comment: Thanks Peter... I upgraded to karate version 0.8.0 and the issue was still the same. Then I changed from karate-jersey to karate-apache and it started working. So until version 0.6.0 certificate selection works with jersey and after that from 0.7.0 onwards it works with apache.I will be using karate for webservice automation of 180+ services with the hope that certificate selection will continue to work with all future releases. Thanks a lot for this lovely framework. Cheers